# Protecting a Laptop in a Surge-Ridden Area

Tags: laptop, power-management, power

I am traveling to Nepal with a laptop, where power frequently surges and wanes (brownouts).
What do I need to protect the laptop?  A surge protector? Voltage regulator?

Answer (score 7):

Most laptop power supplies cope with a wide range of input voltages and coupled with the battery itself, effectively gives you a UPS. If you are expecting surges, though, a surge protector is a good idea.

The biggest risk, however, *will be theft* and so I'd recommend insurance, a decent cable lock, keep all valuable data, photos etc. on [encrypted](http://truecrypt.org/) USB sticks that you keep with you or locked in a hotel safe (where applicable) at all times.

Comment: @digitxp. Hi, I have no objections to minor & technical edits to my posts, but please don't add links to commercial software that I haven't specifically endorsed or mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Acknowledged, my apologies.

Comment: "Most laptop power supplies cope with a wide range of input voltages"? Says who? Is there good evidence to back up your statement that modern laptops are protected by the kind of power surges experience in Nepal, as the OP is asking about.

Comment: Furthermore, it will say right on the laptop charger: Only connect to a grounded outlet. Outlets in southeast Asia are rarely grounded, despite having 3 prongs.

Answer (score 0):

I would also make a complete image of the hard drive before leaving and then wipe the drive and restore the image when you get home.

You don't want any trojans, viruses, etc from connecting to foreign networks getting introduced to your network when you get home.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you back up any changes that take place between the image you make before you leave and your computer when you get home!